# How to put ovals inside the boxes?

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class CGLinesGrid extends JFrame {
    public CGLinesGrid () {
        super ("Exercise 4");
        setSize (500, 500);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint (Graphics g) {

        for (int i = 1; i<=9 ; i++) {
            g.drawLine(70, 30+i*40, 390, 30+i*40);              
            g.drawLine(30+i*40, 70, 30+i*40, 390);
        }
        for (int i = 1; i<=9 ; i++) {
            g.drawOval(70, 20+i*40, 40, 10+i*30);
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        CGLinesGrid draw = new CGLinesGrid();
        draw.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I created an 8x8 grid. I want to put ovals inside of them. Can u help me? :(

Comment: Don't override `paint`. You are supposed to override the `paintComponent` method instead.

Comment: I didn't get your point. Sorry i'm a beginner :(

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things before getting to a solution.

First, as @RealSkeptic said, **never** call the `paint()` method from within your component. Always use the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method.

Second, when calling the `paintComponent()` method always call the paintComponent method for its parent class using

```
super.paintComponent(g);
```

Third, the paintComponent() method shouldn't be called directly on the `JFrame`, use a `JPanel`.

Now on to the solution.

You want a 8x8 grid of squares, each with a circle inside the square.

The simplest way to do this is to use a `JPanel` that has a `GridLayout` and add 64 `JLabel`'s to it. Each `JLabel will then print a square and circle in that square.

Starting from the bottom we need to create a JLabel that prints out the square and circle:

```
class SquareWithCircleLabel extends JLabel {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        //notice the call to its parent method
        super.paintComponent(g);

        //draw the square and circle
        g.drawRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        g.drawOval(1, 1, this.getWidth() - 1, this.getHeight() - 1);
    }
}
```

Next we need a `JPanel` that contains all these `JLabel`s in an 8 x 8 grid:

```
class PaintPanel extends JPanel {
    PaintPanel() {
        //give it a 8 x 8 GridLayout 
        setLayout(new GridLayout(8, 8));

        //add 81 labels to the JPanel and they will automatically be formatted into a 9 x 9 grid because of our GridLayout
        for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
            add(new SquareWithCircleLabel());
        }
    }
}
```

Now we need to simply add this `JPanel` to our `JFrame` in the constructor

```
add(new PaintPanel());
```

The complete code looks like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class CGLinesGrid extends JFrame {
    public CGLinesGrid () {
        super ("Exercise 4");
        setSize (500, 500);
        add(new PaintPanel());
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        CGLinesGrid draw = new CGLinesGrid();
        draw.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    class PaintPanel extends JPanel {
        PaintPanel() {
            setLayout(new GridLayout(9, 9));
            for (int i = 0; i < 81; i++) {
                add(new SquareWithCircleLabel());
            }
        }
    }

    class SquareWithCircleLabel extends JLabel {
        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            g.drawRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
            g.drawOval(1, 1, this.getWidth() - 1, this.getHeight() - 1);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Sir Yitzih, the codes u gave doesn't work on my Java? Idk why. There are errors in the 2 classes u added.

Comment: It says that the hierarchy of of the 2 classes are inconsistent. :(

Comment: sir can u make the codes more simpler? I'm confused coz i'm a beginner